# Adding map index to an index of toponyms

Tags: xindy

I have a book with a lot of toponyms and several maps at the end.

I have made an index of toponyms using package `multind` and a lot of commands like `\index{geo}{Australia}` inside the text.

I use `xindy` and get lists of pages where these toponyms are mentioned, like

```
 Australia    10, 23-25
```

Now I want to add the position on the map(s) into this index, so it will look like

```
 Australia    10, 23-25, II:A1-K9, IV:B2-C4
```

where `II` & `IV` are the numbers of the maps, `A1-K9` & `B2-C4` are the map grid squares, covering Australia.

How can I do it?

Probably I should define some command like `\mapindex{2}{A1-K9}` using `\index{map}{...}`, and give instuctions to `xindy`, but I have no idea about the details.

Of course, I can edit my `.ind` file manually, but that's not the way I want to do it ;-)

Comment: Please add something compilable, not just fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, that was not too difficult.

Here is `map.xdy` I wrote:

```
(define-alphabet "map-letters" ("А" "Б" "В" "Г" "Д" "Е" "Ж" "И"))
(define-location-class "map-place" :var
    ("roman-numerals-uppercase" :sep ":" 
     "map-letters" 
     "arabic-numbers" :sep "-"
     "map-letters" 
     "arabic-numbers"
    )
)
```

`"map-letters"` is just to use Russian letters, you can use `"ALPHA"` instead.

`:var` is important to have variations I:А1 and I:A1-Г3

If I take `geo.idx` like this

```
\indexentry{Австралия|(}{375}
\indexentry{Австралия|)}{381}
\indexentry{Австралия}{447}
\indexentry{Австралия}{489}
\indexentry{Австралия}{IV:А1}
\indexentry{Австралия}{I:Г3}
\indexentry{Австралия}{II:Б2-Д4}
```

and compile it with

```
xindy  -M texindy -M page-ranges  -M map -L russian -C utf8 -o geo.ind geo.idx
```

the I get inside `geo.ind` exactly what I wanted:

```
\item Австралия, 375--381, 447, 489, I:Г3, II:Б2-Д4, IV:А1
```

So I can manually write a file with the coordinates of my toponyms (`toponyms.idx`) and compile my book like this:

```
xelatex ...
xindy ... toponyms.idx geo.idx
xelatex ...
```